# How can I use local nodejs modules in Lambda?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, es6-modules

I have a Lambda nodejs 20.x function that's working fine and now I want to import and use an object from a module called local_util that I wrote and put in a local directory. However, CloudWatch logs for the Lambda now show:

```
Cannot find module '/var/local_util/index.js' imported from /var/task/index.js
```

How can I get Lambda to find my module? I've never tried to import my own nodejs module before.

I created a directory called "local_util" one level up from the directory of my lambda code, put my new module's index.js there.

```
// local_util/index.js

const lock = {
  get: async function (thing) {
     // reinvent AWS distributed lock management because it's so fun...
  },

  release: async function(thing, id) {
    // more fun...
  }
};

export { lock };
```

Then I ran "npm init" and added this line to the new package.json:

`"type": "module",`

Now I have this tree:

```
lambda/
|__my_lambda_func/
   |__index.js
   |__package.json
   |__package-lock.json
   |__node_modules/
|__local_util/
   |__index.js
   |__package.json
```

In my_lambda_func/index.js I added this line:

`import { lock } from '../local_util/index.js';`

Finally I did `npm install --install-links ../local_util` and then `zip -qr function.zip .` while in the my_lambda_func/ directory. When I deploy the new function.zip and invoke its function then I get the `Cannot find module '/var/local_util/index.js' imported from /var/task/index.js` error in CloudWatch.

Here's the full error:

```
{
    "errorType": "Error",
    "errorMessage": "Cannot find module '/var/local_util/index.js' imported from /var/task/index.js",
    "code": "ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND",
    "url": "file:///var/local_util/index.js",
    "stack": [
        "Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/var/local_util/index.js' imported from /var/task/index.js",
        "    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:406:5)",
        "    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:238:11)",
        "    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:850:10)",
        "    at moduleResolveWithNodePath (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:972:12)",
        "    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1091:79)",
        "    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:383:12)",
        "    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:352:25)",
        "    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:228:38)",
        "    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:85:39)",
        "    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:84:36)"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to change my import statement from

```
import { lock } from '../local_util/index.js';
```

to

```
import { lock } from './node_modules/local_util/index.js';
```

This fixed it because relative to the root of my uploaded .zip file, `./node_modules/local_util/index.js` is actually where the module file was.